# javascript reference error while trying to implement mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I am new to javascript and I am trying to create a simple mvc app.

This is my **model.js**:

```
     function Question(question,hint,answer){

        this.question = question;
        this.hint = hint;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
```

This is my **view.js**:

```
    function view(modelList){
    this.modelList = modelList;

    }

view.prototype.show = function(){
   var length  = this.modelList.length;
   for(var i=0;i<length;i++){
         alert(this.modelList[i].question);
         console.log(this.modelList[i].question);
   }
};
```

This is my **controller.js**:

```
    function controller(modelList){
      this.view = new view(modelList);
    }


controller.prototype.show = function(){
     this.view.show();
};
```

This is my **index.html**:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="controller.js"></script>
  <script src="model.js"></script>
  <script src="view.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>


</html>
```

When I run index.html on my browser, I am getting a error like this:

> jQuery.Deferred exception: model is not defined ReferenceError: model is not defined
>       at HTMLDocument. (file:///D:/Javascript/MVC/app.js:3:23)
>       at j (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:29948)
>       at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js:2:30262) undefined

and

```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: model is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (app.js:3)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am wrong??

ThankYou

**EDIT**:

This is my **app.js**:

```
    $(function(){

     var model1 = new model("question","hint","answer");
     var model2 = new model("question2","hint2","answer2");

     var modelList = {model1,model2};

     var controller = new controller(modelList);
     controller.show();


});
```

Comment: I just added app.js

Comment: nope still the same error

Comment: I strongly suggest you paste all your code to https://jsfiddle.net and get it working there (with our help). And then paste back into individual files once you fix the problem. This back-and-forth is progressing very slowly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/weeuedub/ this where I have uploaded the code please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/weeuedub/1/

1. Added jQuery as a dependency (which you don't need to do in your own app).
2. Renamed your `controller` class to `Controller`.

The problem was this line:

```
var controller = new controller(...);
```

Because you were using the variable name "controller", it overrides the "controller" function declared above.

As a convention, try naming your classes starting with an uppercase letter.

**Update**: https://jsfiddle.net/weeuedub/2/

You were assigning `modelList` as `{ model1, model2 }`, which is not an array you can iterate through by getting the `length`. It's an object that is identical to: `{ model1: model1, model2: model2 }`. This is ES6 syntax that is not widely supported by browsers yet, and I assume it was just a typo on your part. The fix was to change that to `[ model1, model2 ]` to get an array.

Comment: where can i view the console in jsfiddle ! did alert box show up for you??

Comment: It's the regular JS console of your browser.

Comment: Thankyou it was really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Your model.js defines a `Question function`

You should either change it to

`function model(question,hint,answer){}`

or change the instantiation to `Question`.

```
var model1 = new Question("question","hint","answer");
var model2 = new Question("question2","hint2","answer2");
```